# In languages with quotative markers, is extraction allowed out of quotative-marked clauses?

Tags: syntax, theoretical-linguistics

That is, is there a language that allows the following type of movement

1. WH1 ... (ATTITUDE-VERB) QUOT ... t1
2. DP-TOP1 ... (ATTITUDE-VERB) QUOT ... t1

Comment: What would such structures look like? Can you show (however ill-formed) examples with English?

Comment: I suppose it would be something like: `Who did John_i say, "I_i talked to"?`  (Where "_i" is a subscripted index; I'm attempting to exploit the shifting of indexicals in English quotations to demonstrate what the reading would have to be.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about specific cases of *wh*-movement, but Japanese allows long-distance scrambling out of a quotative clause, which seems to be a positive answer to your question. For instance, here's an example adapted from Saito (1992):

```
[Sono hon-o]_i    Hanako-ga    [CP Taroo-ga t_i katta to]     omotteiru.
that book-ACC     Hanako-NOM   Taro-NOM         bought QUOT   think
'Hanako thinks Taro bought that book.'
```

In general I don't think I've ever heard of quotative clauses being islands, so I'd expect in *wh*-movement languages with quotatives you'll be able to do the type of extractions you're talking about.

Saito, M. (1992). 'Long Distance Scrambling in Japanese.' [*Journal of East Asian Linguistics* 1(1): 69-118.](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00129574)

Comment: Hello Supergrunch! Welcome to the Linguistics SE! I fixed your interlinear gloss. Please double check it in case there are mistakes, I was not sure about the "bought QUOT" part... :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and fixing the gloss! The "bought QUOT" part should be right - the Japanese quotative is a head-final complementizer and so occurs at the end of the clause.